# C++ delegating ctor and parent ctor with argument

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

This does not seem to work in C++11:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B(const A& a)
        : A(a)   // parent constructor for passing the parameter
        , B()    // delegating constructor for init of other members
    {};
  // ...
};
```

gcc tells me that `an initializer for a delegating constructor must appear alone`.

How do I both call the constructor of the parent class with the parameter, and call the basic constructor of the B class? (I have a bunch of other constructors in B that need the same behavior).

Right now I am considering writing a private `B::init()` function and use it in all constructor bodies, but that tastes a bit much of C++03.

What is the preferred solution?

Comment: Why not write in the other direction ? `B::B() : B(A{}) {}` and `B::B(const A&a) : A(a), other_member{}{}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why not write an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Barry: Not sure If I don't miss something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the preferred way of delegation is the other way around, it's not meant to be used to refactor common parts of constructors, but rather to define the simpler one as a special case of a the more complex case.

So you should start with `B(const A& a)` and use this as delegation target.

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() : B(A());
    B(const A& a) : A(a)   // parent constructor for passing the parameter
    {};
};
```

You are calling `A()` anyways when creating `B`.

The rationale behind it is when you have two "partially specialized" c'tors, you wouldn't be able to use them to initialize the complex one. E.g:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() {};
    B(int) : B() {};
    B(double) : B() {};
    B(double,int) : B(int), B(double) {}; // can't do it.
};
```

I believe the technical reason is explained in Bathsheba's answer. Look what would happen if you had a common part in `B()`:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() {};
    B(int) : B() {};
    B(double) : B() {};
    B(double,int) : B(int), B(double) {}; //ooops would get B() called twice!
};
```

It's the diamond problem known from inheritance. The solution is to reverse the logic.

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() : B(0,0) {};
    B(int a) : B(a,0) {};
    B(double d) : B(0,d) {};
    B(double a, int d) {/*full implementation*/};
};
```

Comment: Plus one for providing a solution, unlike my answer ;-)

Comment: Looks like a plagiarism of Barry's comment =/. But I started writing it before it was posted.

Comment: There's not harm in doing that in my opinion: comments are the poor cousin of an answer as the former are not so easily peer-reviewed, and there is no acceptance mechanism.

Comment: I see. Given the variation in the constructor signatures in my real-life `B`, I might stick to a `B::init()`...

Comment: @Bathsheba Yea, well, rationalizing even a simple answer also takes time and effort.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, copy-pasta leftover. Thanks. Two times it's on purpose I beleive, the comment is clear enough. And sorry for misreference, it was your comment, and Barry replied to that.

Answer (score 2):

`B(const A& a) : A(a), B()` does not make sense since `B()` will *also* initialise the base class `A`. That would essentially be a duplicate initialisation, which is an inherent contradiction.

The only real option for the language is to disallow anything else if you use a delegated constructor. That's what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: Sorry, comment removed.

Comment: So it's a conflict because `B()` calls `A()`, but then I try to *also* call `A(a)`, correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct! You can't construct the same object twice.